# Как адаптировать сайт под все мобильные устройства?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как адаптировать сайт под все мобильные устройства?

Я адаптировал для примера под свой телефон с разрешением ширины 360, всё отображается, как мне нужно. Потом открыл на другом телефоне, там ширина экрана больше на 20 и всё поплыло, так как на это разрешение не прописаны медиа-запросы.

Как это правильно делается, чтобы каждое мобильное устройство отображало как надо?

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться - что такое "как надо"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Прописать правильный вьюпорт:

   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
2. Определиться с [медиа-запросами](http://css-live.ru/articles-css/pravilnye-kontrolnye-tochki-v-css.html) - какие контрольные точки и в какую сторону использовать. Выбрать, какие именно разрешения нужны, а так же в какую сторону вы их применяете. Есть 2 основных подхода - mobile и desktop first. Это поможет избавиться от неразберихи какие стили что переназначают/перебивают на конкретной контрольной точке;
3. Для мобилок использовать относительные величины для ширины, а не жесткие, как `360px`. Например, всему сайту задать `width: 100%;` а контейнеру-центровщику `width: 80%;`. Но и контент внутри контейнера должен тянуться конечно же.

Несколько статей для изучения темы:

- [Как превратить обычные сайты в адаптивные?](https://habr.com/company/UXDepot/blog/225365/)
- [Адаптивная вёрстка сайта, урок первый. Вёрстка главной страницы](https://html5book.ru/adaptivnaya-vyorstka-sayta/)
- [Основы адаптивного веб — дизайна (Responsive). Или как сделать
  простой шаблон адаптивным.](http://beloweb.ru/novichkam/osnovyi-adaptivnogo-veb-dizayna-responsive-ili-kak-sdelat-prostoy-shablon-adaptivnyim.html)
- [Адаптивная верстка: что это и как использовать](https://tproger.ru/translations/responsive-web-design-tips/)

Comment: Относительные, вплане, проценты или vh?

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните, что означает второй пункт. Раскройте, если не сложно. Спасибо!

Comment: медиа  запросы это вот это `@media (max-width: n){query}` но они бывают разные почитайте в сети

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я знаю, что такое медиа-запросы. Я попросил разъяснить, что означет "определиться с медиа-запросами и какие контрольные точки в какую сторону использовать"

Comment: определиться это значит выбрать какие именно разрешения нужны

Comment: 1) Относительные, вплане, проценты или vh? - процентов будет достаточно, например все будет 100% а контейнер max-width: 80%; 2) Определиться это значит выбрать какие именно разрешения нужны, верно сказал Павел. А так же в какую сторону вы их применяете, есть 2 основных подхода - mobile и desktop first. Это поможет избавиться от неразберихи что и когда переназначает на какой контрольной точке

Comment: если говорить именно о адаптивной вёрстке то размеры как раз в px и доходя до предела переделывают вёрстку если говорить о резиновой вёрстке то делают в процентах если о адаптивно резиновой то это самый универсальный способ ... но есть ещё и flex который в разы облегчает

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я определил, мне нужны все мобильные устройства. Но они бывают разных разрешений, как угодить под каждый, вот цель моего вопроса

Comment: а нету таких запросов по скольку каждый день выходя новые девайсы и всегда с новыми разрешениями есть универсальные ...тоже в сети куча примеров и копипастить смысла нету

Comment: Например от 0 до 767 - мобилки, 768 до 1024 - десктоп и тд. От 0 до 767 полностью закроет необходимый диапазон

Comment: Хорошая статься почитать для начала http://css-live.ru/articles-css/pravilnye-kontrolnye-tochki-v-css.html

Comment: от 0 до 768 есть ещё и 480 и 640 а это apple device и многие самсунги и так же 0 960 до 1200 это и планшеты и так же apple ноуты - в общем способов милилон и гаком а вот умение попасть в них уже искуство